# How to fill in Null values in a column of a PySpark DataFrame using value from other records?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, null

I have a PySpark DataFrame with columns 'Country' and 'Continent'. In several records, value of 'Continent' is missing. However, there are records containing 'Continent' for the same country (Examples of "Italy" and "China" in the sample dataset below).

```py
# Prepare Data
data = [
    (1, "Italy", "Europe"),
    (2, "Italy", "Europe"),
    (3, "Italy", None),
    (4, "Italy", None),
    (5, "China", "Asia"),
    (6, "China", None),
    (7, "Japan", "Asia"),
    (8, "France", None),
]

# Create DataFrame
columns = ["Code", "Country", "Continent"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

[image]

For records whose 'Continent' is Null, I want to:

- Look for any record of the same country whose 'Continent' is not Null
- Get the value of 'Continent' and fill in the Null value

The expected output will be like:

| Code | Country | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'Italy' | 'Europe' |
| 2 | 'Italy' | 'Europe' |
| 3 | 'Italy' | 'Europe' |
| 4 | 'Italy' | 'Europe' |
| 5 | 'China' | 'Asia' |
| 6 | 'China' | 'Asia' |
| 7 | 'Japan' | 'Asia' |
| 8 | 'France' | Null |

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one of the solution. Assuming there is only 1 distinct `Continent` value in each country, you can use the `max()` within each country partition:

```py
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "Continent",
    func.when(
        func.col("Continent").isNull(),
        func.max("Continent").over(Window.partitionBy(func.col("Country"))),
    ).otherwise(func.col("Continent")),
).orderBy("code")
```

```
df2.show(truncate=False)

    +----+-------+---------+
    |Code|Country|Continent|
    +----+-------+---------+
    |1   |Italy  |Europe   |
    |2   |Italy  |Europe   |
    |3   |Italy  |Europe   |
    |4   |Italy  |Europe   |
    |5   |China  |Asia     |
    |6   |China  |Asia     |
    |7   |Japan  |Asia     |
    |8   |France |null     |
    +----+-------+---------+
```

Or you can create a smaller "reference" dataframe and do the broadcasting join back to the main dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works on a static DataFrame well. But, when I use it for a streaming DataFrame, I get an error: "Non-time-based windows are not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets;".
Is there any way to solve this issue? I am running notebook in a DLT pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, same result :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window 

df.withColumn(
    "continent",
    F.coalesce(
        F.col("continent"),
        F.first("continent").over(Window.partitionBy("country")),
    ),
).show()
```

```
+----+-------+---------+
|Code|Country|continent|
+----+-------+---------+
|   5|  China|     Asia|
|   6|  China|     Asia|
|   8| France|     null|
|   1|  Italy|   Europe|
|   2|  Italy|   Europe|
|   3|  Italy|   Europe|
|   4|  Italy|   Europe|
|   7|  Japan|     Asia|
+----+-------+---------+
```